# Issue with using an array to store/print files from Linux

Tags: java, arrays, file, loops, for-loop

I cant figure out how to loop through this instead of just repeating the code, bugging the hell outta me!  FYI assignment has already been turned in using 5 iterations of code, just wanted to learn how to implement the string array holding file contents into a for loop for future knowledge.  I have tried for a few hours but it just prints the filename, cant seem to get the file contents.

```
/*************************************************************************
* LinuxSys.java
*
* This program reads text from a file 
**************************************************************************/

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LinuxSys {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String systemInfo[] = new String [5];
        int i = 0;
        // using _ to simulate file paths to test on local cpu, as it is easier/quicker 
        // than logging onto server/copy pasting code into new pico file
        systemInfo[0] = "_proc_sys_kernel_hostname.txt";    //local files 
        systemInfo[1] = "_proc_meminfo.txt";              //local files
        systemInfo[2] = "_proc_version.txt";              //local files
        systemInfo[3] = "_proc_sys_kernel_hostname.txt";    //local files
        //systemInfo[0] = "_proc_sys_kernel_hostname.txt";  //local files


        // 1st try to print server host name file
        try {
            BufferedReader inputStream =
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader(systemInfo[i]));
            String line = "blank";
            while (line != null) {
                if((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    i++;  // increment systemInfo[] array position
                } // end if
            } //end while
            System.out.println(); // create space
            inputStream.close();
        } // end try 
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File was not found");
            System.out.println("or could not be opened");
        } //end catch
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading from file");
        } //end catch

        // 2nd try to print server memory file 
        {
            BufferedReader inputStream =
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader(systemInfo[i]));
            String line = "blank";
            while (line != null) {
                if((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    i++;  // increment systemInfo[] array position
                } // end if
            } //end while
            System.out.println(); // create space
            inputStream.close();
        } // end try 
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File was not found");
            System.out.println("or could not be opened");
        } //end catch
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading from file");
        } //end catch

        // 3rd try to print version file 
        try {
            BufferedReader inputStream =
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader(systemInfo[i]));
            String line = "blank";
            while (line != null) {
                if((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    i++;
                } // end if
            } //end while
            System.out.println(); // create space
            inputStream.close();
        } // end try 
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File was not found");
            System.out.println("or could not be opened");
        } //end catch
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading from file");
        } //end catch
    } // end main
} // end class
```

Comment: did yoou print the value of i and see what its pointing to ?

Comment: Can you also not what you are trying to achieve in the code.

Comment: Just FYI - you're missing the 2nd `try`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i < systemInfo.size; ++i)
{
     // the code you want to repeat with i varying each time
}
```

or

```
int i=0;
while(i < systemInfo.size) 
{
     // the code you want to repeat with i varying each time
     ++i;
}
```

or

```
int i=0;
while(i++ < systemInfo.size) 
{
     // the code you want to repeat with i varying each time
}
```

or

```
int i=0;
do
{
     // the code you want to repeat with i varying each time
}
while(++i < systemInfo.size)
```

or...